# Insert video on my other user playlist

Tags: php, youtube-api

Well, I have an youtube account with some playlists that I update daily, automatically through a server-side script that runs on a cron job. When Google decided to merge google+ accounts with youtube, this account became some sort of secondary account to my G+ one, now I have to login to my google account and select that one to enter it.

Now my scripts stopped working because I can't access that account using a script. "$youtube->playlistItems->insert" gives me a "forbidden" exception because I'm trying to insert an item in a playlist that I don't own, and apparently I can't get an access token for the account with the playlists that I want to update with the scripts for some reason. When I try to login with that one to get a token, I get a "forbidden" error.

So, is there any way to get a token for it or to give access to my other account to change my playlists? Or at least any way to update it using a server side script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I understand your problems.
I'm currently struggling with these changes in my application.
However users have reported a workaround:

Just to explain what changed:
Before the change you had a Google account linked with several changes. Accessing this account granted you access to all channels.

2 channels -> 1 account

Now:
Every channel is linked to it's own Google account.

2 channels -> 2 accounts

Therefor you need to login to your **new account**. To do this, login to YouTube, select the channel you want to use and open https://plus.google.com/u/0/settings Here you'll find an email adress `channelname-numbers@pages.googleplus.com` and can set up a password.

Use these credentials to authenticate and you should have full access again.